# Get token from AcquireTokenAsync return 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, access-token, adal, sharepoint-online

I have a single page web application. When I AcquireTokenSilent it through error "`Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken`". In my function I also check if there is such an error like that, I will call AcquireToken instead, then I'm able to get token.

The problem is I cannot use that token when I access my resources (Sharepoint and Graph), it through error: "`The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`"

This is my function:

```
var _appCredentials = new ClientCredential(_aadConfig.ClientId, _aadConfig.ClientSecret);

public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string resource)
{
    try
    {
        var token = await _authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, _appCredentials, new UserIdentifier(_userId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
        return token.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (AdalException ex)
    {
        var token = await _authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, _appCredentials);
        return token.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

I understand that the exception is expected when AcquireTokenSilentAsync function not able to get the access token in the cache and refresh token failed. When it doesn't through the exception, I can use the token perfectly, so there is no issue with the permission.

When AcquireTokenSilentAsync through an exception, I expect that the token I get in AcquireTokenAsync should be the same as AcquireTokenSilentAsync but it is not.
I cannot access my resource.

I use Sharepoint and Graph resource, the APIs that I use are:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.GetItems(CamlQuery myquery)
clientContext.Load(items, its => its.Include(
                      i => i["Title"],
                      i => i["ID"],
                      i => i["Author"],
                      i => i["Created"],
                      its => its.ListItemCollectionPosition);

// excute query
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

GraphClient.Me.Planner.Tasks.Request()
```

The exception is as below:

```
   at Service.SharePointService.<GetDocumentTemplatesByCategoryId>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\WORKING\PROJECTS\develop\Service\SharePointService.cs:line 55
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Apps.SPA.Controllers.DocumentController.<GetDocumentTemplatesByCategoryId>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\WORKING\PROJECTS\develop\Apps.SPA\Controllers\DocumentController.cs:line 107
```

I also attach my decode token, which is generated from AcquireTokenAsync but will return 401 Unauthorized error when I query documents in Sharepoint.
[image]

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what is the resource you are acquiring token for , and which api you want to call in your requirement . What is the detail error message with 401 error

Comment: Hi Nan Yu, I am acquiring token for Sharepoint and Graph. For Sharepoint, I use this api: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.GetItems(CamlQuery myquery)
clientContext.Load(items, its => its.Include(
                      i => i["Title"],
                      i => i["ID"],
                      i => i["Author"],
                      i => i["Created"],
                      its => its.ListItemCollectionPosition);

// excute query
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
For Graph, I use Task: 
GraphClient.Me.Planner.Tasks.Request()

Comment: what is the resource you are using with AcquireTokenAsync function ? do you acquire different token for different resource ?

Comment: Dear Nan Yu, the resource that I pass to above function are https://graph.microsoft.com and https://xxx.sharepoint.com. Yes I got 2 different tokens for each resource, but both of them return 401 error message.

Comment: Then please use fiddle to see the requests and check what's the inner error message .

Comment: Dear Nan Yu, I did capture the request by using fiddle. Please help to take a look. Thanks.